# Ошибка установки плагина ADT

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse

При установке ADT выскакивают ошибки:

> `Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: Android Development Tools 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853)
>   Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found`

Хотя SDK обновил до 17 версии. Операционка Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите видео. Там все очень хорошо показано. Я сам пока не нашел это видео получал ту же ошибку, что и Вы.
[Смотреть](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCNC34BflOo)